pug creates newline character in mixin when using block keyword
This example
mixin article
  div
    if block
      block

+article Test

When inspecting the code it looks like one space, but if we start editing the text node we will see this:
<div>Test
                </div>

How to get rid of this?

There doesn't seem to be a way to avoid this in Pug, but because of the way HTML handles whitespace it shouldn't affect the way a page displays to the end user.
You could consider running an html formatting package after Pug runs to clean up Pug's output.

Additionally, if your block truly is just a string, you could use a mixin parameter instead (but I doubt this is actually the case):
mixin article(text)
  div #{text}

+article('Test')

<div>Test</div>

